# How do i force an image inside a button tag to occupy the exact width and height of the button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a button element, but i'll like to have an image inside. The image has been designed in Photoshop already. The image size exceeds that of the button and i want to force it to occupy the exact size of the button so that it maintains the behavior of button elements but what is displayed is the image onto the button.

I've tried setting the border-width, padding and overflow property of the button element to 0px and hidden respectively. I also set the max-width property of the image to 100%

```
<button class = "col-sm-5" style= "border-width: 0px; padding: 
 0px; overflow: hidden;">

    <img src= "photos/myImg.png" style= "max-width:100%;">

</button>
```

I expect no borders of any kind, but i get a grey border between the image and the button.
[Button/Image behavior screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbyRc.png)

Comment: have you tried using the image as `background-image` on the button?

Comment: Hi @joshua, I noticed that you're using bootstrap with the class `col-sm-5`. That's incorrect usage of the grid class. Enclose the button inside `<div class="col-sm-5"></div>` and remove `col-sm-5` from button tag. After that, please put your question in a code or snippet so we could run the code and help you thoroughly. Thank you.

Comment: thanks, @JerdineSabio I took your correction and did some more research. I have figured out the issue.

Comment: thanks, @JerdineSabio I took your correction and did some more research. I have figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BUTTON {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;   
    background: #f0f0f0 url([url or base 64 data]);
    background-position: 8px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution although it didn't solve my problem as the image full size is now displayed breaking out of the button element.